# Create new child node in D3 tree on click

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, tree

I'm trying to modify a D3 collapsible tree layout so that when I click on a leaf node I also create a new child for that node. This new child should persist if I collapse and re-expand the tree, and should be able to have children of its own on future clicks.

In the code below, for example, if I click on the "animate" node and then on its child "Transitioner," I want that to create a new node with "Transitioner" as its parent.

Here is the code for the layout I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>d3.chart.layout.hierarchy.tree.cartesian</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/misoproject/d3.chart/master/d3.chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/bansaghi/d3.chart.layout.hierarchy/master/d3.chart.layout.hierarchy.js"></script>
    <style>
      html {
        display: table;
        margin: auto; }

      #vis {
        width: 960px;
        height: 500px; }

      .node {
        cursor: pointer; }

      .node circle {
        fill: #fff;
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 1.5px; }

      .node text {
        font-size: 11px; }

      path.link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #ccc;
        stroke-width: 1.5px; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="vis"></div>

    <script>
      (function() {

        function radius(d) {
          return Math.log(d.size);
        }

        d3.json("https://rawgit.com/bansaghi/d3.chart.layout.hierarchy/master/examples/data/flare.json", function(error, json) {

          var tree = d3.select("#vis").append("svg")

           .chart("tree.cartesian")

             .margin({ top: 0, right: 180, bottom: 0, left: 40 })
             //.radius(radius)
             .sort(function(a, b) { return d3.descending(a.size, b.size); })
             //.zoomable([0.1, 3])
             .collapsible(1)
             //.duration(200)
             ;

           tree.draw(json);
        });
      }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```